# How to use mapped types function values in TypeScript without casting?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I have an object that maps *type names* to builder functions, and I would like to be able to invoke the builders in a type safe way by passing them the name for the type of object they build...

Something like this:

```js
const builders = {
  type_a: () => ({
    foo: 'hello',
  }),
  type_b: () => ({
    bar: 'good bye',
  }),
};

type TypeNames = keyof typeof builders;

type ResultType<T extends TypeNames> = ReturnType<typeof builders[T]>;

export function build<T extends TypeNames>(typeName: T): ResultType<T> {
  const builder: () => ResultType<T> = builders[typeName]; // this is the conflicting line
  return builder();
}
```

But it gives the following error:

```
Type '(() => { foo: string; }) | (() => { bar: string; })' is not assignable to type '() => ReturnType<{ type_a: () => { foo: string; }; type_b: () => { bar: string; }; }[T]>'.
  Type '() => { foo: string; }' is not assignable to type '() => ReturnType<{ type_a: () => { foo: string; }; type_b: () => { bar: string; }; }[T]>'.
    Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<{ type_a: () => { foo: string; }; type_b: () => { bar: string; }; }[T]>'
```

It is as if the compiler was ignoring that `typeName` type is a specific type parameter `T` and not just the more general `TypeNames`. No matter how I rewrite it (declaring the return types separately and the builders return parameters referencing them instead of using `ReturnType<...>`, using interfaces themselves for the builders, etc.) I always end up with the same kind of error, `typeName` is not narrowed down to a single instance of `T`).

Any ideas about how to solve it?

If I remove the functions and change to simple values it just works as expected:

```js
const singletons = {
  type_a: {
    foo: 'hello',
  },
  type_b: {
    bar: 'good bye',
  },
};

type TypeNames = keyof typeof singletons;

type ResultType<T extends TypeNames> = typeof singletons[T];

export function build<T extends TypeNames>(typeName: T): ResultType<T> {
  return singletons[typeName];
}
```

Comment: The compiler is not smart enough to infer that the intersection of those two partial objects effectively matches the return type. Are you ok with casting? ` return ... as EventType<T>`.

Comment: @tokland actually, the conflicting type is not in the result of `Object.assign`, but in the `partialBuilders[eventName]()`, if I cast just that to `PartialEvent<T>` it will swallow it